# Adding instances of class to arraylist

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist, instance

I am trying to add instanes of a class(basically a node) to my arraylist. How do i go about doing this? heres what i have:

```
public class Sentence {
    String word;


    public Sentence(String word){
         this.word=word;

    }

}
```

and then in another class:

```
ArrayList<Object> holder= new ArrayList<Object>();
Sentence node;
String name;
//Something to initialize/set name
holder.add(new node(name));
```

Bu that doesnt seem to work, i get error: cannot find symbol for node.

Comment: You don't define what a node is.  You do however define what a sentence is.

Answer (score 1):

Either of these should work:

```
holder.add(new Sentence(name)); //if name is initialized
```

or

```
holder.add(node); //if node is initialized
```

However, remember to actually initialize `name` and `node` before trying to use them! Also, if you intend to only store `Sentence` objects in the ArrayList, you could just define it as `ArrayList<Sentence>`:

```
ArrayList<Sentence> holder= new ArrayList<Sentence>();
```

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList<Object> holder= new ArrayList<Object>();` Here when you write this you need to specify what type of data your `Arraylist` can hold. In your case as you are trying to add `Sentence` type into your `ArrayList` you should change it to. `ArrayList<Sentence> holder= new ArrayList<Sentence>();`
specifying that `ArrayList` holder will be holding elements of type `Sentence`.

And while adding do `holder.add(new Sentence(name));` because when you do `holder.add(new node(name));` the compiler fails to understand what a `node` is. `node` is just a reference of type `Sentence` nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes what is node, constructor can be called by class name and that is `Sentence`

```
holder.add(new Sentence(name));
```

Answer (score 0):

`node` is variable name rather than a type. Initialise `name` and `node` then the node reference can be added to the `List`

```
name = "foo";
node = new Sentence(name);
holder.add(node);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass an instance to an object or not. Either way works:

```
Sentence node = new Sentence(name);
holder.add(node);
```

OR

```
holder.add(new Sentence(name));
```

The decision of which to use comes up to whether you wish to use your `node` instance for something else other than passing it as an argument to `new Node()`.